# NSButton default button with blueish look

Tags: cocoa, user-interface

I have a dialog with 1 or more buttons and want to be able to programmatically set the rightmost one be the default one, so that when the user presses the Enter or Return key it should respond as if the user clicked it.

I'm using `[btn setKeyEquivalent:@"\r"]` and that makes it work fine but I want the button to have the blueish look which isn't happening. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I was missing to set the button bezel style properly and that's why it didn't look properly. I'm now setting the button as this:

```
[btn setBezelStyle:NSRoundedBezelStyle];
```

Then any of these work to set the default button:

```
[myWindow setDefaultButtonCell:[btn cell]];
```

or

```
[btn setKeyEquivalent:@"\r"]
```

Comment: Just soiled myself with excitement seeing this solution. Unbelievable that I didn't think of forcing a button to be the default button cell and forcefully setting the key equivalent. Sometimes you do *have* to do this, even when your NSView contains a key with its shortcut set to return. Strange, but true. Thanks!

Comment: In Interface Builder you must choose the style `Push`. I went through all 15 styles Interface Builder offers and only `Push` glows blue when set as the default button cell in OS X 10.8.3 (Mountain Lion.) Other types will take on the return key as their equivalent key and become the default button, but only the `Push` button glows blue when it does so. I haven't tested at all on other versions of OS X - it's very possible that this note wasn't necessary in Snow Leopard(?) when this question was asked and answered in 2009.

Answer (score 8):

My setting has been a custom sheet where I wanted the default button to appear like within an NSAlert. The following configuration gives me the blue default appearance. Works in 10.12.3 Sierra.

```
   button.bezelstyle = NSBezelStyleRounded; // Push in Interface Builder
   button.keyEquivalent = @"\r";
   button.highlighted = YES; // this is the most important part.
```

Comment: minor quibble: "bezelstyle" should be "bezelStyle". [\pendantic] ;-)

Answer (score 6):

The documentation says:

> Note that if you set the key equivalent to Return, that button becomes the default button.

Thus, you're doing it correctly. You could try this after setting the key equivalent:

```
[button setNeedsDisplay:YES];
```

This forces the button to redraw itself.

Comment: Does it still render blueish under Yosemite and above? It doesn't appear to for my dialogs - even though the key equivalent is Return (little down-left arrow symbol).

Answer (score 2):

For Swift 4.2 just use

```
button.isHighlighted = true
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[myWindow setDefaultButtonCell:[btn cell]]; // should do the trick.
```

See [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/setDefaultButtonCell:) for more details.