# SwiftUI : How do you display a tooltip / hint on hover?

Tags: tooltip, swiftui

how to display tooltip / hint on some view? 
As example, on the button.

[image]

Comment: The approach will be the same as I described in answer on your question about `acceptsFirstMouse`

Comment: @Asperi I believe I saw native modificator for this. But I cannot remember where I saw it and google telling me nothing.

Comment: @Asperi This question encompases a separate part of the UI platform, so it's good to have it be a separate question. If/when Apple adds support for either one of the two separate concerns, it will likely not be the same solution and they might not arrive at the same time, so having this separated out into two questions helps the overall community, especially as new answers crop up

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to both [Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4423545/andrew) and [Sorin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8066735/sorin-dolha) for the solution direction. The presented solutions mostly worked but when I used them they totally messed up the layout. It turns out that the Tooltip has its own size, frame etc. which isn't automatically matching the content.

In theory I could address those problems by using fixed frames etc. but that did not seem the right direction to me.

I have come up with the following (slightly more complex) but easy to use solution which doesn't have these drawbacks.

```swift
extension View {
    func tooltip(_ tip: String) -> some View {
        background(GeometryReader { childGeometry in
            TooltipView(tip, geometry: childGeometry) {
                self
            }
        })
    }
}

private struct TooltipView<Content>: View where Content: View {
    let content: () -> Content
    let tip: String
    let geometry: GeometryProxy

    init(_ tip: String, geometry: GeometryProxy, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content
        self.tip = tip
        self.geometry = geometry
    }

    var body: some View {
        Tooltip(tip, content: content)
            .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
    }
}

private struct Tooltip<Content: View>: NSViewRepresentable {
    typealias NSViewType = NSHostingView<Content>

    init(_ text: String?, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.text = text
        self.content = content()
    }

    let text: String?
    let content: Content

    func makeNSView(context _: Context) -> NSHostingView<Content> {
        NSViewType(rootView: content)
    }

    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSHostingView<Content>, context _: Context) {
        nsView.rootView = content
        nsView.toolTip = text
    }
}
```

I have added a `GeometryReader` to the content of the tooltip and then constrain the size of the Tooltip to the match the size of the content.

To use it:

```swift
Toggle("...", isOn: $isOn)
   .tooltip("This is my tip")
```

### Addition January 2023

The latest release of SwiftUI requires a small change in the `tooltip` method. I noticed rapid redrawing problems. By adding a `ZStack` this problem is addressed:

```swift
extension View {
    func tooltip(_ tip: String) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            background(GeometryReader { childGeometry in
                TooltipView(tip, geometry: childGeometry) {
                    self
                }
            })
            // self
        }
    }
}
```

Feb 2023: I removed the second self. With the extra self there is a glow on the parent.

Answer (score 39):

**SwiftUI 2.0**

As simple as

```
   Button("Action") { }
     .help("Just do something")

   Button("Action") { }
     .help(Text("Just do something"))
```

Comment: maybe it will not work in release version of SwiftUI 2.0:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64148126/value-of-type-has-no-member-help-after-update-to-latest-stable-xcode-r

Comment: This would be the best solution, but I just tried it and it has no effect. I expected that hovering the mouse over the button show the text, but it doesn't.

Comment: I got this to work fine for a macOS app running deployment target of 11.0 and Xcode 12.3.

Comment: Can confirm as @NickN mentions this seems to be working nicely on macOS (currently using Xcode 13 Beta 5 on Big Sur 11.5.2)

Answer (score 23):

## 2020 | SwiftUI 1 and 2 both

In swiftUI 2:

```
Toggle("...", isOn: $isOn)
    .help("this is tooltip")
```

In swiftUI 1 there is really no native way to create a tooltip.
But here is a solution also for this:

```
import SwiftUI

@available(OSX 10.15, *)
public extension View {
    func tooltip(_ toolTip: String) -> some View {
        self.overlay(TooltipView(toolTip))
    }
}

@available(OSX 10.15, *)
private struct TooltipView: NSViewRepresentable {
    let toolTip: String
    
    init(_ toolTip: String) {
        self.toolTip = toolTip
    }
    
    func makeNSView(context: NSViewRepresentableContext<TooltipView>) -> NSView {
        NSView()
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSView, context: NSViewRepresentableContext<TooltipView>) {
        nsView.toolTip = self.toolTip
    }
}
```

and usage:

```
Text("some text with tooltip")
    .tooltip("some tooltip")
```

Comment: This doesn't work with a custom ButtonStyle, described here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58419161/issue-with-buttons-in-swiftui-on-macos

Comment: Is there any reason this solution initializes `toolTip`in `TooltipView`as an Optional?

Comment: 2 more: `@available(OSX 11.0, *)` is not necessary, because it also works in 10.15, below SwiftUI is not available anyways, so we can leave it out entirely. Plus, the main benefit is that it does work in 10.15, otherwise we could use `.help(..)`. And `import Foundation` is not necessary, it will import with SwiftUI.

Comment: It works in Vision Pro.

Answer (score 2):

When the overlay isn't good enough, e.g. you want the tooltip on a control that accepts mouse events (and an overlay would not allow clicks through), such as Toggle, a solution may be to use a Host view that internally includes a NSHostingView itself - that supports a tooltip being an AppKit view - eventually loading further SwiftUI content inside:

```
struct Tooltip<Content: View>: NSViewRepresentable {
    typealias NSViewType = NSHostingView<Content>

    init(_ text: String?, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.text = text
        self.content = content()
    }

    let text: String?
    let content: Content

    func makeNSView(context: NSViewRepresentableContext<Tooltip<Content>>) -> NSViewType {
        NSViewType(rootView: content)
    }
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSViewType, context: NSViewRepresentableContext<Tooltip<Content>>) {
        nsView.rootView = content
        nsView.toolTip = text
    }
}
```

This does have some caveats regarding sizing when used with certain SwiftUI content (and then you may hopefully use fixedSize() or a frame(width:height:) to get it working as you need), but it's otherwise easy to use:

```
Tooltip("A description") { 
    Toggle("...", isOn: $isOn) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct TooltipText: View {
    @State private var isActive = false
    
    let text: String
    let helpText: String
    var body: some View {
        Text(isActive ? helpText : text)
            .padding( isActive ? 6 : 0)
            .background(Color.white)
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 3)
                    .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: isActive  ? 1 : 0)
            )
            .animation(.easeOut(duration: 0.2) )
            .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                        .onChanged( { _ in isActive = true } )
                        .onEnded( { _ in isActive = false } )
            )
    }
}
```

use:

```
TooltipText(text: "sum of squares:", helpText: "sum of data (with mean subtracted) squared")
```

Comment: Thank you and welcome @user3585825, Can you include an explanation.

Answer (score -1):

you can also do this in interface builder (laying out your view graphically in Xcode). when you add the button the "Identity Inspector" tab - the previous tab to the default "Attributes Inspector" on the panel to the right of the screen... also has a field for "Tooltip".