# Custom ToolTip in swiftUI for iOS

Tags: swiftui, tooltip

I have a row of colors and I want to display a ToolTip for each of the colors.

```
struct ColorsView: View {
    let colors = [UIColor.red, UIColor.white, UIColor.gray, UIColor.blue, UIColor.black]
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(0..<colors.count) { index in
                Color(self.colors[index])
                .frame(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 30) / 5, height: 25)
            }
        }.cornerRadius(12)
    }
}
```

How can I create a custom toolTip for this? I tried wrapping in a ZStack but this doesn't seem to solve the problem exactly. Any help :)

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59129089/how-do-you-display-a-tooltip-hint-on-hover

Comment: @Asperi 'help' modifier is not yet supported in swiftUI 1.0 right?

Comment: Right, but the referenced topic contains many other answers, which work for SwiftUI 1.0.

Comment: @BeeEm97 Just to confirm - you want this tooltip for a macOS app, right?

Comment: @pawello This is to be done for iOS app, not for macOS. Thanks :)

Comment: @BeeEm97 How do you want to trigger this tooltip? For macOS it's just by hovering. How do you want to do it for iOS?

Comment: @pawello, just as a button tap so to say.

Comment: @BeeEm97 One button for all? One button for every colour?. And how do you want your tooltip to be presented? As an alert in the center of the screen? - See, your question is not clear enough :)

Comment: @pawello2222 Sorry, if that doesn't make sense. But this is to be achieved as any popTip view would look like. To be more precise, I looked for a library that implements this - AMPopTip. Hope this provides some insights into what exactly is to be achieved :).

Comment: @BeeEm97 For iPadOS you can use popover. For iOS you may need to use a library. They are usually created if some feature is missing/broken/can be significantly improved - and this is the case here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219420/discussion-between-beeem97-and-pawello2222).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try using this tool: https://github.com/quassummanus/SwiftUI-Tooltip

Here's an example of how you could use it with a simple `Text` view, you can extrapolate from there. It's very nice because it doesn't rely on any Apple-provided APIs that are not fundamental to SwiftUI, so you can use it on all platforms.

```swift
Text("Say something nice...")
    .tooltip(.bottom) {
        Text("Something nice!")
    }
```

And you get something like this:

[image: example]

Comment: I opened a ticket on the repo, but readers should be aware that this package is not currently usable due to all types being internal.