# How to show a description when the user clicks on a button

Tags: swift, swiftui

I would like to show a description of how to using the function when the user clicks on the question mark. I tried to do it like this, but it wouldn't show the description when I click on the question mark.

```
Text("?") 
.hoverEffect(.lift) 
.onTapGesture { 
    Text("Description") 
}
```

[Example of how I want to make it look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Emafo.png)

Comment: I think the challenge here is that we don't know what programming language you are using so I suggest you go back to edit the question and be sure to tag it with some relevant language tags.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/63285228/12299030?

Comment: @Asperi Thank you for the link. I used it and it still doesn't show anything when I click on the button.

Comment: I think the Apple common way would be to use a popover, if you'd to follow the user guidelines