# In SwiftUI, How do I increase the height of a button?

Tags: swift, macos, user-interface, button, swiftui

As you can see in the screenshot, the button height does not adjust to fit the text size, making it look ugly. How can I increase the hight of the buttons, so it does not look stupid. My question is, how do I increase the height of buttons in SwiftUI? I am trying to make the titlescreen of my Minecraft-like game.

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        VStack (spacing: 8) {
            Text("[Name not disclosed]Craft").font(.system(size: geometry.size.width/8))
            Button(action: {
                
            }) {
                Text("Singleplayer").font(.system(size: geometry.size.width/20))
                    .frame(minWidth: geometry.size.width/2)
            }
            Button(action: {
                
            }) {
                Text("Multiplayer").font(.system(size: geometry.size.width/20))
                    .frame(minWidth: geometry.size.width/2)
            }
            HStack (spacing: 8) {
                Button(action: {
                    
                }) {
                    Text("Options").font(.system(size: geometry.size.width/20))
                        .frame(minWidth: (geometry.size.width/4)-16)
                }
                Button(action: {
                    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
                }) {
                    Text("Quit Game").font(.system(size: geometry.size.width/20))
                        .frame(minWidth: (geometry.size.width/4)-16)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Not nicely looking window]

Comment: See: https://www.appcoda.com/swiftui-buttons/

Comment: See answer here on how to create a custom button style: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58419161/issue-with-buttons-in-swiftui-on-macos

Answer (score 33):

You just need to set `PlainButtonStyle` and draw it as you wish...

Here is for example one of your button:

```
Button(action: {
    
}) {
    Text("Singleplayer").font(.system(size: geometry.size.width/20))
        .padding()
        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).fill(Color.blue))
        .frame(minWidth: geometry.size.width/2)
}
.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
```

[image: custom button]

Comment: As noted above, the frame modifier should be before the background modifier otherwise the blue will not fill the whole frame

Answer (score 10):

Please try below Code:

```
Button(action: {
       //do action       
}) {
    Text("SIGN IN")
        .frame(width: 200 , height: 50, alignment: .center)
        //You need to change height & width as per your requirement
}
 .background(Color.blue)
 .foregroundColor(Color.white)
 .cornerRadius(5)
```

> Output
>   [image]

Answer (score 8):

##### - For increasing the size of the clickable button:

You must increase the size of the `label` of the button instead of changing its frame:

```
Button {
    // Perform action here
} label: {
    Text("Hello")
        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
}
```

---

##### - For holding the area, without being clickable:

Use the simpler initializer if you need only a title for your `Button`:

```
Button("Click me") {
    // Perform action here
}
.frame(width: 100, height: 100)
.background(Color.yellow)
```

[image: Preview]

**Note that** `frame` modifier must come before `background` to make it looks larger. Otherwise, you can't see the difference.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved my day, your "Note that" part made a magic!

Comment: The problem with this approach is that only the text is tappable, the whole yellow background isn't.

Comment: Downvote because this approach is broken. Like the previous commenter said, only the text portion of the button is tappable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change height of the stack

```
struct ContentView: View {

   @State private var arr = ["String"]

    var body: some View {

         GeometryReader { geometry in
                VStack (spacing: 8) {
                    Text("[Name not disclosed]Craft").font(.system(size: geometry.size.width/8))
                    Button(action: {

                    }) {
                        Text("Singleplayer").font(.system(size: geometry.size.width/20))
                            .frame(minWidth: geometry.size.width/2)
                    }
                    Button(action: {

                    }) {
                        Text("Multiplayer").font(.system(size: geometry.size.width/20))
                            .frame(minWidth: geometry.size.width/2)
                    }
                    HStack (spacing: 8) {
                        Button(action: {

                        }) {
                            Text("Options").font(.system(size: geometry.size.width/20))
                                .frame(minWidth: (geometry.size.width/4)-16)
                        }
                        Button(action: {
                            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
                        }) {
                            Text("Quit Game").font(.system(size: geometry.size.width/20))
                                .frame(minWidth: (geometry.size.width/4)-16)
                            }
                    } .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .leading) .background(Color.red)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is geometry here ?