# SwiftUI - Button with transparent background

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to create a game menu which shows a list of different options like 'New Game'.

I've realised that with buttons:

```
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image("Title")
            Group {
                Button(LocalizedStringKey("new"), action: {}
                Button(LocalizedStringKey("load"), action: {})
                Button(LocalizedStringKey("save"), action: {})
                Button(LocalizedStringKey("resume"), action: {})
                Button(LocalizedStringKey("main"), action: {})
                Button(LocalizedStringKey("tutorial"), action: {})
                Button(LocalizedStringKey("credits"), action: {})                         
            }
            .background(Color.clear)
            .font(.custom("Snell Roundhand", size: 24))
            .padding()
        }
    }
```

and it looks like this:
[image]

How can I hide the background rectangle of the button? I want to see only the text. Touching the text should trigger the action.

Comment: I assume the answer in the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59290097/in-swiftui-how-do-i-increase-the-height-of-a-button/59290554#59290554) will be helpful.

Comment: Ok. I'll check. Thanks

Comment: Yes. that was the solution: I just had to add ".buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())". If you want to get the credits for this, you can post it as answer :-)

Comment: Cool. If it was helpful you can just vote up in that post. ))

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Thanks to Asperi to point me into the right direction.

I just had to add

```
.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
```

to the group.

Comment: why does this make the button unclickable?

Comment: may be adding a contentShape modifier would help ?