# Changing button color breaks formatting in Appkit SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, appkit

I am a web developer attempting to do a simple SwiftUI app and I googled this before asking here, but I am still in troubles.

This is the UI of a small app that I am doing. And I'd like to change the color of my button.
[image]

This is the code that I am trying after reading some examples online:

```
Button(action: {
  self.device.setAsDefaultInputDevice()
  self.refresh()
}) {
  Text("Default")
    .padding()
    .background(Color.purple) // 2. Change the background color to purple including the padding
    .foregroundColor(.white)  // 3. Set the foreground/font color to white
    .font(.body)
}
```

As I add padding to the Text, everything looks wrong, I was completely fine with the shape of the default button.
My final intention is to swap primary/secondary system color depending if default is ON.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/59290554/12299030?

Comment: Where does `geometry` comes from in that example?

Comment: That helped anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Button(action: {
  self.device.setAsDefaultInputDevice()
  self.refresh()
}) {
  Text("Default")
    .padding(.leading)
    .padding(.trailing)
    .padding(.top, 2)
    .padding(.bottom, 2)
    .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4).fill(Color.blue))
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to your answer so that others can learn from it.