# How do I corrent my Button's View with SwiftUI on MacOS App

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I have written a content view with one button. The actual format of the button is in another view, but that isn't the issue.

I have tried numerous 'solutions' to this, but have written a very cut down example of the bad button.

As you will see from the screen shot attached, I have a gray 'button' behind the green button I actually want. Also, the green button has the top missing as it should have rounded corners and the word Start should appear in the middle of the box. This is very strange (to me!).

I am hoping that somebody will be able to tell me what is wrong with my Views.

Here is my screen shot!

[This looks very strange to me!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCNTB.png)

Now for the code

ContentView:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Button(action: {
                print("Got here")
            }, label: {
                ActionButton()
            })
            Spacer()
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}
```

ActionButton:

```
struct ActionButton: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack (alignment: .center) {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                .foregroundColor(Color.green)
            Text("Start")
                .bold()
                .foregroundColor(.black)
        }
        .frame(width: 80, height: 45)
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Copy pasting the code into a fresh xcode project (12.1), and the button looks finde to me. Can you provide more code so that the problem is reproducible?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59290554/12299030?

Comment: Thank you very much for the good replies.
I solved the problem by adding - .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle()) - after the button code. Thanks @Asperi for your help.

Comment: Thank you @Mamaessen for correcting my code. This was my first question, and I wasn't sure how to do things correctly. In future, I would like to include a screenshot and not just a link to one.
Once again, thanks.