# Modify SwiftUI DefaultButtonStyle to show Background on macOS

Tags: macos, button, swiftui, colors

I am trying to modify the Background of a SwiftUI Button for macOS with `DefaultButtonStyle`.

Using `.background(Color.red)` on the Button works, if System `dark` Mode is used by the User, but in `light` Mode, a none opace view is blocking the background Color:

[image]

I don't want to use a custom `ButtonStyle` as this would mean to rebuild all the behaviour of a DefaultButton, so `ViewModifier` seems to be the way to go.

Inspecting the Button in XCode, reveals that a View called `NSButtonBezelView` is blocking the way. (Blue Selection)

[image]

**How can this be modified (Blue Selection)?**

```swift
// The Button View
struct MyDefaultButton: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button{
            
        } label: {
            Text("Button")
        }
        .defaultButtonStyle()
    }
    
}

// Modify the DefaultButtonStyle to keep everything as it is
// except BackgroundColor
struct DefaultButtonStyle: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .background(Color.red)
            
            // What has to be modified here to adjust NSButtonBezelView ?
            // ??
    }
}

// Extend Button to use the defaultStyle
// using it directly via .buttonStyle(...) is not possible
extension Button {
    func defaultButtonStyle() -> some View {
        self.modifier(DefaultButtonStyle())
    }
}

// Preview for .light and .dark Mode
struct DefaultButtonView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            ForEach(ColorScheme.allCases, id: \.self) {
                MyDefaultButton()
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color(NSColor.windowBackgroundColor))
                    .preferredColorScheme($0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

<sub>Xcode 13.2.1, BigSur 11.6.2</sub>

Comment: Probably you just need to use another button style - this should be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/59290554/12299030.

Comment: Nope this is not what i am looking for; PlainButtonStyle does not have any Borders, Default Shades are missing, it is completely different to DefaultButtonStyle. There is no Style that has the default behaviour

Comment: `DefaultButtonStyle` means system-default, if you want to have custom color background it is already not default.

Comment: Yes, but normally you could Subclass/override; looking for a technique like that in this SwiftUI case.

Answer (score 0):

like this?

[image]

```
struct DefaultButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .padding(.horizontal, 8)
            .padding(.vertical, 3)
            .background(Color.red)
            .cornerRadius(8)
            .shadow(radius: 2)
    }
}
```

You can use it on a Button with:

```
    .buttonStyle(DefaultButtonStyle())
```

Comment: thank you, but unfortunatelly not the answer. Your missing all animations and click actions ( for example the default highlighting, when clicking, behavior in system dark and light mode, opacity, accessibility...)
My Question asks explicitly how to modify the Blue Selection, not a workaround to keep the background red. :)