# Tappable area of Button and Image in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

```
    Button(action: {
       print("Round Action")
       }) {
       Text("Press")
       .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
       .foregroundColor(Color.black)
       .background(Color.red)
       .clipShape(Circle())
       }
       .background(Color.blue)
```

I want the actual button to be tappable and not the square blue frame around it, also is there any way we can just get rid of that frame but could still be able to size that button?

[Button Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6JF6.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issue with Buttons in SwiftUI on MacOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58419161/issue-with-buttons-in-swiftui-on-macos)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `.contentShape` for your Button, by default it's a `Rectangle`:

```
Button(action: {
    print("Round Action")
}) {
    Text("Press")
        .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
        .background(Color.red)
        .clipShape(Circle())
}
.contentShape(Circle()) // <- here
.background(Color.blue)
```

---

> is there any way we can just get rid of that frame but could still be able to size that button?

You can try to use `padding` or `scaleEffect` but `frame` is the recommended way of changing the width and height of a view.