# How do I make a default button in macOS SwiftUI?

Tags: macos, swiftui

I’ve build the following modal dialog in SwiftUI:

[image]

But I can’t figure out how to make the “Open” button be a default button (i.e. filled with blue in standard macOS HIG). The code for it looks like this:

```swift
struct
OpenLocationView : View
{
    @State private var location: String = ""

    var body: some View
    {
        VStack
        {
            HStack
            {
                Text("Location:")
                TextField("https://", text: $location) { self.openLocation() }
            }

            HStack
            {
                Spacer()
                Button("Cancel") { /* dismiss window */ }
                Button("Open") { self.openLocation() }
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(minWidth: 500.0)
    }

    func
    openLocation()
    {
    }
}
```

I tried appending `.buttonStyle(DefaultButtonStyle())`, but that had no visible effect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI on Mac - How do I designate a button as being the primary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57283931/swiftui-on-mac-how-do-i-designate-a-button-as-being-the-primary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: April 2024, this is no longer an issue and the above will work as expected.

This is currently not possible in SwiftUI, see this question and workaround [SwiftUI on Mac - How do I designate a button as being the primary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57283931/swiftui-on-mac-how-do-i-designate-a-button-as-being-the-primary)

Comment: That’s an astonishing oversight. What is the purpose of `DefaultButtonStyle` then? Thank you for the workaround.

Comment: This answer is no longer true.  The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65090827/169346) works fine with Xcode 15/macOS 14

Answer (score 21):

On macOS 11, it is possible to define a keyboard shortcut using the `keyboardShortcut` view modifier.

The standard keyboard shortcuts `.cancelAction` (ESC key) and `.defaultAction` (Enter key) also apply a special coloration to the associated button.`

```swift
Button("Cancel") { ... }
    .keyboardShortcut(.cancelAction)
Button("Open") { ... }
    .keyboardShortcut(.defaultAction)
```

Comment: for Return it should be  .keyboardShortcut(.defaultAction) and it will stop to work as soon as you customise your button style.

Comment: For me, this is not working anymore in macOS 12. You need additionally a `.onSubmit { }` on the TextField or at the `VStack`, if you have more TextFields. It's very annoying, because you need to write the same code as in the Button action twice.