# Preventing tab from committing macOS SwiftUI TextField?

Tags: macos, swiftui, textfield

Is there any way to prevent the onCommit action of a SwiftUI `TextField` from being called when the user presses the Tab key while a field is in focus? In my case, I only have a single text field, and I only want to take action if the user presses Return or Enter.

The header docs for `TextField` say:

```swift
    ///   - onCommit: The action to perform when the user performs an action
    ///     (usually the return key) while the `TextField` has focus.
```

which implies that it should be possible to configure what keys result in commit. But I can’t figure out how.

Comment: Could you instead use a button to perform the action, like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57283931/swiftui-on-mac-how-do-i-designate-a-button-as-being-the-primary

Comment: Yes, that's probably a decent workaround. Just clunky because SwiftUI is incomplete.